# Url.Action method not generateing the correct URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two calls in a jQuery script to the `@Url.Action()` method and I can not figure out why the first call generates the correct URL but the second does not.

```
    .jqGrid( 'navButtonAdd', "#SectionsPager", {
        caption: "Add&nbsp;",
        title: "Add new section.",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
        onClickButton: function ()
        {
            location.assign( "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" );
        }
    } )
    .jqGrid( 'navButtonAdd', "SectionsPager", {
        caption: "Edit&nbsp;",
        title: "Edit selected cell.",
        buttionicon: "ui-icon-edit",
        onClickButton: function ()
        {
            location.assign( "@Url.Action("EditSection")");
        }
    } );
```

If I view the source for the page the first call correctly generates the URL `/DataArea/` (the controller and view are in the `Area` named "DataArea"). but the second call just Generates `/DataArea/Sections/` which is the URL of the page it is rendering on. I have even tried

`"@Url.Action("EditSection", "Section")");`

but it does the same thing. Why is the second call not generating the correct URL?

Comment: Something to note, if I change the first `Url.Action` to EditSection it fails to render the URL correctly too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it but I am not sure why it was broken. In my .cs file I was using:

```
    [Route]
    public ActionResult EditSection()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Which, according to all the documentation I can find, mean that the route should be `/EditSection` and I could even access it via that route if I typed the URL in my browser. After playing around a bit I ended up using

```
    [Route("EditSection")]
    public ActionResult EditSection()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and now the `@Url.Action("EditSection")` is working right. I think it might be a bug in the new mvc5 attribute routing. I am going to play with it more and send a report to MS if I can determine it really is a bug.